# Tail bounds of reciprocals

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, expectation, distribution-tails

Suppose one knows that for a random function $f(n)$, $f(n)-a$ decays at some rate given by: $$Pr(|f(n)-t|>\epsilon)=g(\epsilon),$$for $g(\epsilon)\to0$, all as $n\to\infty$.

If the above holds, then plainly in addition to $f(n)\to a$, we have $1/f(x)\to 1/a$.

But at what rate?

Comment: You need a sequence of RV's to talk about a rate.

Comment: Is the question better now, @Batman?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since
$$
\bigg| \frac1{f(n)}-\frac1a \bigg| = \frac1{|af(n)|} \cdot |f(n)-a|,
$$
as soon as you know the order of magnitude of $|f(n)-a|$ and $|f(n)|$, you know the order of magnitude of $\big| \frac1{f(n)}-\frac1a \big|$.

Comment: This almost makes sense to me, but your expression still has a $1/af(n)$. In the case where $a=1$, for instance, you are still left with $1/f(n)$, which was the original question. So I'm not sure this is a complete answer. Am I missing something?

Comment: It seems actually that you've showed that the rates are the same, since assuming $a\neq 0$, $1/|af(n)|$ converges to a nonzero constant.

Comment: Aha, good point. Yes, the rates are the same then, up to that factor $1/a^2$.